# "Native Libraries not loaded - dropping message " -- Android - Unity as a Library

Tags: android, kotlin, unity-game-engine, android-library, aar

I have been searching for days, I used the exact same implementation guide as in the demo (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/uaal-example/19LTS-21LTS/docs/android.md), which worked fine for the demo but when using the exact same process with my unity project I keep getting this error when I try and use mUnityPlayer.sendMessage() :

W/Unity: Native libraries not loaded - dropping message for #######.#########

I've looked through the the two projects to find a difference and the only one I see is that in the libs folder when they are exported unity exports multiple .aar folders in our project along with the unity-classes.jar file and just the unity-classes.jar file for the demo. The other difference is our project has these scripts nested instead of just on the top level folder.

I have tried multiple editor versions and that doesn't work either. How do I make my android project load these native libraries so I can integrate the unity project?

Comment: i'm facing same issue since 2 days. did you find a resolution? Thanks